# Facebook doesn't recognize alternative languages until I use the debugger on that language

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, localization

Facebook doesn't recognize alternative languages until I use the debugger on that language. This means I could potentially ping all the urls through the debugger and my problem is solved. But this is of course far more than ideal. Anyone any ideas?

To reproduce the problem:

1. Take a look at:

   http://poules.com/nl/wk-2014/poules/totoboeren
   (make sure the language is set on Nederlands in the bottom right corner)
2. Click on a name in the list, and then press the knop 'Delen' (Dutch for share).
   You'll see that the description in the Share dialog is in **English**, while it should be in **Dutch**
3. Then, launch the Facebook debugger:
   https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/

   enter the url in the data-href-tag of the page, i.e:

   [http://poules.com/int/world-cup-2014/pools/totoboeren/members/[namehere]?fb_locale=nl_NL](http://poules.com/int/world-cup-2014/pools/totoboeren/members/%5bnamehere%5d?fb_locale=nl_NL)
4. repeat step 2 and you'll see the description in the **share dialog is now in Dutch**.

Conclusion:
I could fix this issue by pinging the FB debug url for every url and every language I have in my page, but I rather am looking for a less of a hacky way :) anyone an idea what is wrong?

**More information**

'See exactly what our scraper sees for your URL' in the FB debugger:

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/echo?q=http%3A%2F%2Fpoules.com%2Fint%2Fworld-cup-2014%2Fpools%2Ftotoboeren%2Fmembers%2Fdirk-boer%3Ffb_locale%3Dnl_NL

Comment: same here; /tools/debug/og/echo shows dutch, yet recrape info shows english